# Mongodb: Sum values in the sub documents after group, then lookup, then unwind

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: orders_A and orders_B (web and app orders) with the same structure:

```
orders_A:

{"_id": 100001,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 10,
"record_id": 11111,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "12/07/2018"},

{"_id": 100002,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 15,
"record_id": 11112,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "13/07/2018"}

orders_B:

{"_id": 102201,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 5,
"record_id": 22222,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "09/07/2018"},

{"_id": 102202,
"customer_id": 200001,
"order_value": 5,
"record_id": 22223,
"related_product": "No",
"Date_of_order": "10/07/2018"}
```

What I need to do is answer "what's the total value of customer 200001 orders from A and B?"

Here is what I have so far:

```
db.orders_A.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    customer_id: 200001}},

  {$project: {
    customer_id:1,
    order_value:1}},

  {$group: {
    _id: "$customer_id",
    value_of_orders_a: {$sum: "$order_value"}}},

  {$lookup: {
    from: "orders_B",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "customer_id",
    as: "orders_B"}},

  {$unwind {
    "path": "$record_id", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}}.pretty()
```

What this outputs is this:

```
"_id": 200001,
"value_of_orders_a": 25,
"orders_b": {
    {"_id": 102201,
    "customer_id": 200001,
    "order_value": 5,
    "record_id": 22222,
    "related_product": "No",
    "Date_of_order": "09/07/2018"},

    {"_id": 102202,
    "customer_id": 200001,
    "order_value": 5,
    "record_id": 22223,
    "related_product": "No",
    "Date_of_order": "10/07/2018"}
```

**I want to make a "value_of_orders_b" and then finally, a "total_orders_value" which is the summation of these two fields**

When I try to group again and do this after the unwind:

```
{ $group: {
  _id: "_id",
  value_of_orders_a: {$first: "$value_of_orders_a"},
  value_of_orders_b: {$sum: "$orders_b.order_value"}}}.pretty()
```

I get the output:

```
"_id": 200001,
"value_of_orders_a": 25,
"value_of_orders_b": 0
```

**Why is it showing zero?!** I can see from the original code that I do have order_b orders associated with that user!

The desired output is:

```
"_id": 200001,
"value_of_orders_a": 25,
"value_of_orders_b": 10
```

And what i'd love to get is this output:

```
"_id": 200001,
"total_value_of_orders": 35
```

Comment: I'm using MongoDB version 4.0.1

Comment: Shouldn't this be `{$unwind {
    "path": "$orders_B", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}}` ? Rest all looks good to me.

Comment: The reason I didn't use unwind at that level is so that the first group isn't duplicated otherwise, i'd get a document from orders_B under {_id": 200001,
"value_of_orders_a": 25}. The way i'm done it is so that there's a single document for the orders_A aggregation, and its child is the orders_B documents.

Comment: If that makes sense? Kind of difficult to write out. But then again, my approach may be completely wrong, i've been playing with MongoDB for 3 days now

Comment: Actually you  don't both `$unwind` and `$group`. You can replace that with `$project` stage.Something like `{$project:{value_of_orders_a:1, value_of_orders_b:{$sum:"$orders_b.order_value"}}}`

Comment: I actually thought that that was what I was doing before after unwind with my group with this: { $group: {
  _id: "_id",
  value_of_orders_a: {$first: "$value_of_orders_a"},
  value_of_orders_b: {$sum: "$orders_b.order_value"}}}

Comment: I'll try both yours and Anthony's suggestions to try to understand better-  thanks for taking the time

Comment: If you just need total of both orders you can use `{$project:{total_value_of_orders:{$add:["$value_of_orders_a",{$sum:"$orders_b.order_value"}]}}}` after `$lookup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `$unwind` and `$group` after `$lookup` with below `$project` stage.

Keep all the stages until `$lookup` as is and add the `$project` stage at the end.

```
{$project:{total_value_of_orders:{$add:["$value_of_orders_a",{$sum:"$orders_b.order_value"}]}}}
```

Comment: Do you know why this would not be counting the b orders? There isn't an error, and i've followed your instructions exactly

Comment: Can I see your query ? Just to clarify your last two stages should be lookup and project

Comment: I made a mistake with the name of the field during the sum - it doesn't throw errors but obviously couldn't find what to count. Thanks for all your help today

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation from monogodb **3.6** and above

```
db.orders_A.aggregate([
  { "$limit": 1 },
  { "$facet": {
    "orders_B": [
      { "$match": { "customer_id": 200001 }},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "orders_B",
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$customer_id", 200001 ] } } },
        ],
        "as": "orders_B"
      }}
    ],
    "orders_A": [
      { "$match": { "customer_id": 200001 }},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "orders_A",
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$customer_id", 200001 ] } } },
        ],
        "as": "orders_A"
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": { "$concatArrays": [ "$orders_A", "$orders_B" ] }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$customer_id",
    "total_value_of_orders": { "$sum": "$order_value" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Would you mind explaining the purpose of limit : 1 at the start? It doesn't make sense to me intuitively, since we aggregating and matching on a certain customer_id. Is it basically stopping duplicates?

Comment: For not taking the `orders_A` collection again into the query because we already taken them in `$facet`(`orders_A` and `orders_B`)...

Comment: It is just a cool way to do aggregation with the multiple collection if the other collections have same data structure... and lastly we merge their data using `$concatArrays` and perform other aggregation on them as I used `$group` at last